# TeX menu missing in WinEdt install

Tags: installing, winedt

I just installed WinEdt build: 20170413 (v. 10.2) on Windows 10.
the main menu item TeX is missing;
also in the Execution Modes config, there are no tabs of either Tex System or Tex Options.
Can someone help?

(I installed the same build on Windows 7 earlier, all fine; also to add, I installed MikTex 2.9 before WinEdt install)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A TeX distribution like MiKTeX or TeX Live is installed?

Comment: Yes I installed MikTex 2.9 before installing WinEdt, all looks fine for that.

Comment: compared with my other install on win7. They have in common those: File,Edit,Search,Insert,Document,Project,View,Tools,Macros,Accessaries,Options,Windows,Help. Also under menu item Insert in my Windows10 install, there was only two items:insert file and date, to my surprise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

There can be an only reason to have WinEdt not showing its "TeX" menu without manual customizations: you have accidentally switched configuration...

To overcome this problem, go to "Options" -> "Configurations" menu and click "Default (Auto-Detect)". Everything will be back again.

### A little explanation

WinEdt can be used for different purposes other than TeX editing.

Excerpt from the documentation:

> WinEdt is used as a front-end for compilers and typesetting systems, such as TeX, HTML or NSIS.

From the "Options" -> "Configurations" menu you can choose what to use WinEdt for.

[image]

Choosing "Default (Auto-Detect)", WinEdt will detect your installed TeX distribution and you can use it for all the mentioned tasks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, to you and to  Heiko Oberdiek, and all others. Your suggestion click "Default (Auto-Detect)" solved the problem cleanly.